# Principal caesura in unus erat toto line I.6 of Ovid's Metamorphoses

Tags: scansion, ovidius, metre, metamorphoses, caesura

I am scanning Ovid's metamorphoses.  For the line "unus erat toto naturae vultus in orbe," I have - - | - - | - - | - ' ' | - ' ' | - x.  There doesn't seem to be an obvious position for the principal caesura in either the third or fourth foot (toto naturae - - | - ' ' ).  Suggestions?

Incidentally, this line stuck out to me because of the coincidence of natural stress accents with the thesis of every foot of the hexameter.

Answer (score 5):

The line should be scanned:

– u u | – – | – – | – – | – u u | – x ||

The 2nd *u* of *unus* is short, as is the *e* of *erat*. All three syllables of *naturae* are long.

The principal caesura is after the first long syllable in the third foot (between the last syllable of *toto* and the first of *naturae*).

Comment: Thank you!  I feel dumb, but also less so after reading your answer.

The stress/thesis coincidence doesn't appear with proper scansion, but that also makes more sense based on what I understand the line to be conveying.

Comment: @Sura If you've found that this answers your question, make sure to click on the check mark to mark it "answered."